# Using actual object in Unit Test works but Sinon Mocked object does not in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, mocking, sinon

I'm trying to use Sinon to mock dependencies while writing unit test cases. I faced few issues, but finally made it work. But the way it is working appears really weird to me.

Class `Employee` depends on class `Data` and hence `Data` object is dependency injected into the constructor of class `Employee`.

Here is the code that works:

```
class Data{
    getName(){
        return "Ram";
    }
}

class Employee{
    constructor(data){
        this._data = data;
    }

    getName(){
        return this._data.getName();
    }
}

describe('canary suite', function(){
    it('canary test', function(){

        var data = new Data();
        var mockData = sinon.mock(data);        
        mockData.expects('getName').returns('Raj');

        var emp = new Employee(data); //here is the deviation.

        expect(emp.getName()).equals('Raj');
        mockData.verify();
        mockData.restore();
    });
});
```

If i change this line in code:

```
var emp = new Employee(data);
```

to

```
var emp = new Employee(mockData);
```

it gives this error:

> TypeError: this._data.getName is not a function

I have worked with mocks in C# before. But there i passed the mocked object to the constructor. Not the actual object.
 
Could someone help me understand the reason for this behavior with Sinon mocking ?

Answer (score 1):

In a language like C#, along with types/interfaces and public/private scope, the object instances are normally **immutable**. This means it's more common to create a mock as an "empty shell" of the original object's class/interface.

Javascript only recently supports classes and inheritance etc, at it's core it's a [Prototype-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) language.

From Douglas Crockford:

> you make prototype objects, and then … make new instances. Objects are mutable in JavaScript, so we can augment the new instances, giving them new fields and methods. These can then act as prototypes for even newer objects. We don't need classes to make lots of similar objects… Objects inherit from objects.

This is why in Javascript it makes more sense to mock on the original object instance itself, and why Sinon provides `restore()` to remove the mock behaviour.